# Using Arduino as output for Python progam

Tags: python, arduino, usb

I'm trying to control Arduino outputs via USB with python.
Basically if a value x in python is 5, then digital output 5 should be high.

What I had imagined was something like this on the

**Python** side:

```
import serial
import time


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

x=5

while True:
    ser.write('x')
```

**Arduino:**

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
int out;

out = Serial.read();

if (out == 5){
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

}
```

Am I way off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One improvement in python:

```
x='5'

while True:
    ser.write(x)
```

Now, you get '5' in out, not 'x'.

And arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for(char i=0;i<10;i++)
      pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    ;
}

void serialEvent() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    inChar-='0';
    for(char i=0;i<10;i++)
      digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    digitalWrite(inChar,HIGH);
  }
}
```